# AndroidStudio preview class not found org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android-studio

I work with Android Studio 2.1.1. I am writing a class which extends `LinearLayout`. This class has a string attribute which I try to parse with basic android JSON lib in the class constructor. The code seems fine as it compiles and installs to the device. But Android Studio cannot find the class in the Preview (see screenshot below).

What is the solution of problem?
How do I set 'JSON lib' of Android Studio Preview?

[Android Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIXe6.png)

Android Studio error stack:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:154)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:396)
    at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Android Studio 2.2.3, I had the same problem, and sky's workaround worked for me, but I looked deeper and discovered the ClassNotFoundException was caused specifically by a reference to JSONException in code not ever executed in the view draw code needed for the layout preview.  Interestingly, non executed references to JSONObject do not cause a ClassNotFoundException, but apparently the compiler wants to load the JSONException class regardless.

My solution was to catch Exception instead of JSONException in my code (which would be unaffected by the change).  I decided this was preferable to adding the otherwise unnecessary library.

Answer (score 0):

I did found only the WORKAROUND for this kind of issue. I did download 'json-20160212.jar' from maven repo. Then placed it to project's root directory (or other directory you like), and did add the dependency in project's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    provided files('json-20160212.jar')
}
```

I'm using 'provided' scope to avoid json library been compiled with my project, but have an ability to 'preview' my layout without ClassNotFoundException.